# Error reading csv on remote server "Value `null` is not supported as key in maps, must be a non-nullable string."

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a strange problem - I have a local neo4j instance v 2.3.8 and a remote server instance of neo4j v 3.1.4

I am in the process of rebuilding my graph on the remote server using the source files. This has been successful so far - I am able to import the csv files successfully on the remote server - I am accessing the remote server through the browser (remote http connection)

With literally the last file, I get the following error message on the remote server but the same works fine in my local neo4j instance:

> Value `null` is not supported as key in maps, must be a non-nullable
>   string.

The cypher query is:

```
Load csv with headers from "srcfile3.csv" as line
WITH line
return line limit 2
```

The error message seems to be generated from this file in the neo4j code: https://fossies.org/linux/neo4j/community/bolt/src/main/java/org/neo4j/bolt/v1/messaging/Neo4jPack.java, if that helps.

Comment: Can you share the csv that is failing? Also, the query you provided doesn't add anything to the db.... (I'm guessing srcfile3.csv either has a null header or is missing the headers line)

Comment: The query I shared was just a test query to confirm the file can be loaded, the rest of the processing is not relevant to the question. I'm not sure I can share the csv but let me see if I can anonymize it/recreate it.

Comment: I recreated the csv and ensured all headers were in place. This has worked. Thanks for the pointer. Will mark this as closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Recreated the csv from the original xlsx - ensured all headers were in place and the file opened correctly. Thanks to /u/Tezra for the pointer